# Loading huge amount of from ADLS to PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, azure

I need to copy one year of historical data from Azure data lake storage to Azure PostgreSQL database. 1 day data = 65 GB. How can I load that much data in less time

Answer (score 0):

You can try Azure Data Factory. ADF has connectors for both ADLS and Azure Database for PostgreSQL. Refer to below metrics based on network bandwidth and data size for copy activity in ADF:

[image]

[Copy activity performance and scalability guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance)

Below are some sample articles to use ADLS and Azure Postgres with ADF:

[Copy and transform data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory)

[Copy and transform data in Azure Database for PostgreSQL using Azure Data Factory or Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-database-for-postgresql?tabs=data-factory)